# Linear Regression performance in R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I have a problem with R's performance:
[here](https://github.com/johnsunday/Lineal-Regression/blob/master/Script_Miles_Lineal_Regression.r) is my Script.

The problem is that I need to use it in a base with  ~6m of clients  (with one linear model per customer) and it's taking to long to process.

Can anyone help me to improve the performance of my script? I think that the problem is in the `data.frame rbind` function.

Comment: Have you looked at `biglm`?

Comment: On line 26 you are using a "for" loop...In general you should avoid this in R as it slows things down. Try to vectorise your function instead.

Comment: this is probably also very inefficient: results <- `bind_rows(results, row)` . You could preallocate a results vector with i elements

Comment: You want to fit 6million regression models, one for each client? That's an trivially parallel problem and the data science approach would be to rent a few thousand Amazon EC2 systems for a short time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few problems in your script actually, and growing objects (whether using `rbind()` or `bind_rows()` ) seriously messes up your performance. So if you know how many rows you have, start by creating an object with that many rows.

Next, you rely on a data frame. If you just store the info in separate vectors and only combine them in the end, you remove again a ton of overhead. Take a look at following three mockup examples:

```
library(rbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
# The naive way
f1 <- function(n){
  out <- data.frame(x = numeric(), y = numeric())
  for(i in seq.int(n)){
    tmp <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y=rnorm(1))
    out <- bind_rows(out, tmp)
  }
  return(out)
}
# Preallocating memory
f2 <- function(n){
  out <- data.frame(x = numeric(n), y = numeric(n))
  for(i in seq.int(n)){
    out$x[i] <- rnorm(1)
out$y[i] <- rnorm(1)
  }
  return(out)
}
# Using vectors
f3 <- function(n){
  outx <- numeric(n)
  outy <- numeric(n)
  for(i in seq.int(n)){
    outx[i] <- rnorm(1)
    outy[i] <- rnorm(1)
  }
  return(data.frame(x = outx, y = outy))
}
```

On my machine, I get the following timings:

```
benchmark(
  f1(100),
  f2(100),
  f3(100),
  columns = c("test","elapsed","relative","replications")
)
##     test elapsed relative replications
## 1 f1(100)    2.16    27.00          100
## 2 f2(100)    0.34     4.25          100
## 3 f3(100)    0.08     1.00          100
```

Just changing this can seriously cut your running time already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I'm going to try this solution.